# How can be the Dirichlet function continuous in 0?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I don't understand why the Dirichlet function is continuous in 0 because between 0 and the nearest positive rational number there will be an irrational number also between 0 and the nearest negative rational number there will be an irrational too. How can be this function continuous in 0?

Comment: What are you calling the Dirichlet function? The indicator function of the rationals? That is indeed discontinuous even at $0$. But for instance $x$ times the indicator function of the rationals is continuous at $0$, because it basically keeps oscillating between the $x$ axis and the line $y=x$ as you go in towards zero...but those are both going to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Do you mean $$D(x)=\begin{cases}0,& x\textrm{ irrational}\\ 1/b,& x=a/b \textrm{ a reduced fraction}\end{cases}$$

Comment: No, I meant the indicator function of the rationals.

Comment: So you mean if we take f(x): 0 for the irrationals and x for the rationals then between 0 and the nearest rational number it will be an irrational but now f(0) will be 0 unlike the indicator function of the rationals where f(0) was 1.

Comment: Yes, and more importantly the values at irrationals *near* zero are small.